# IE 8 Mixed security content error for HTTPS

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8, https, mixed

I have a web application (.NET 2.0 coded in C#) that displays pages both to logged in users and the general public. When a user logs in, the protocol is switched to HTTPS. The images are being displayed by a CSS file residing in a virtual directory folder. The problem is that when the HTTPS pages are displayed, IE 8 will display a message saying that there is mixed security content on the page. I dont want the user to disable mixed content on their browser, rather, what the web application to furnish the images via HTTPS if the member is logged in.

If the images were in the HTML file, then it would be easy to pass in the server variable specifying the protocol (HTTP or HTTPS) to the HTML page. However, how do I pass a server variable to CSS specifying the protocol? All the path in the CSS file are relative.

e.g. 
body {
      font: 12px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
      color: #000000;
      background: #eadcc8 **url(../images/bg_top.gif**) no-repeat 0 0;
      text-align: center;
      margin: 0px;
}

I am not too familiar with CSS functionality, apart from colors and styles.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There has to be an absolute path somewhere. Visit the https page, look at its source and search for "http:" in it. If that doesn't work, look for it in the files it embeds.

Edit: If that doesn't work for you or you think of it as being too complicated, you can also use Google Chromes Developer Tools (Tab "Resources") to monitor all http requests.

Comment: If that fails, use Fiddler to monitor traffic and see which request goes to http: instead of https

Comment: Hi thejh, thanks for your answer but I know which files are coming from HTTP(images) and HTTPS (aspx page). The problem is that the website & page is HTTPS, the image are from a virtual directory within the CSS, the path is relative (../images/something.gif) for these images the protocol is still HTTP. Wondering what I need to do in the CSS code to make this work.

Comment: @Pritika: And the CSS gets loaded via HTTP?

Comment: Yes, the CSS is getting loaded as HTTP. This code was written by another programmer so I think they are constructing the path in the code behind and not checking the protocol, therefore the default protocol is HTTP, rather than HTTPS.

Comment: @Pritika: Not only images over HTTP trigger a warning, CSS file over HTTP does so, too. You have to load the CSS file via https.

Comment: Thanks thejh. Will use absolute paths instead of relative paths and also specify the HTTPS protocol for all includes (CSS, images & scripts).